# Are nested groups supported?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, usergroups

Are nested groups supported in Azure B2C?

[This page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/261789a4-f519-4073-a54c-da23714a2f19/azure-ad-b2c-group-memberships?forum=WindowsAzureAD) suggests there is some support, because it links to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-limitations#restriction-on-nested-groups

If there are restrictions on them then I assume they are at least partially supported. Unfortunately that page no longer exists.

I couldn't find any information in MSFT docs about the status of this feature.

I've tried their User Voice, but the only thing I found is an entry about plain ["Azure AD"](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/fa8991c1-b125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789) (I thought that is supported already, but it appears it's not if there is an open request about it)

FWIW I cannot add a nested group in the way that's suggested by [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-membership-azure-portal). I don't see that option in the UI, though it lists "0 groups" as members.
[image]

Trying to add a group to another group via [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) results in

```
{"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"An invalid operation was included in the following modified references: 'members'.","innerError":{"date":"2022-04-20T15:32:34","request-id":"7d183819-019a-4f23-b31f-1765dcd7d44a","client-request-id":"7d183819-019a-4f23-b31f-1765dcd7d44a"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wrangling with MSFT support I got an answer that nested groups are not supported in B2C enabled tenants.

> This can be done in Azure AD and not on the B2C AD. Adding a group as a member of another group in Azure AD B2C is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD has [some support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-membership-azure-portal) for nested groups.

B2C has no groups support. Typically, you assign the groups in Azure AD and then access them from B2C via [Graph via REST API](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac).

Comment: Well that's my problem. The instructions you linked to don't work for me (see update in question)